# Handle execv with gdb

Tags: gdb, execv

I am attaching gdb to a process which used `execv` to replace the current image.
Sadly it seems like this is confusing gdb since when the process eventually `std::terminate`s, all I get are addresses with no symbols. Trying to load the symbols does not seem to make any difference.

Also `-ex "set follow-exec-mode new"` did not work.

Comment: This isn't really enough information to help.  It sounds like the exec'd file doesn't have debug symbols.  How are you trying to load the symbols?

Comment: Tried loading via `symbol-file shared_obj.so`

Comment: Did you try attaching to the process after the execv call?